# Closed form solution for $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} (-1)^n \left[1 - (n)^{\frac 1n}\right] $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is there a closed form solution for $$\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} (-1)^n \left[1 - (n)^{\frac 1n}\right] $$

The series converges by the $n$th term test. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%20from%201%20to%20infinity%20of%20%28-1%29%5En%28n%5E%281%2Fn%29%20-%201%29) returns an answer of $\approx 0.201255$. A taylor expansion gives $1 - (n)^{\frac 1n}\sim \frac{\ln(n)}n$, and $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\ln(n)}n = 1/2 (2 \gamma - \ln(2)) \ln(2)$.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRB_constant

Comment: You can never test the convergence of a series using nth term test. The series converges by the alternating series test.

Comment: The wolfram alpha returns sum_(n=1)^∞ (-1)^n (1 - n^(1/n)) = -0.18786 for the input sum [(-1)^n (1 - (n)^(1/n)),{n,1,infinite}]

Answer (score 3):

Note that the evaluation you have made by WolframAlpha has some numerical issue, let try indeed with a large but finite number of terms, as for example [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%20from%201%20to%2010000%20of%20%28-1%29%5En%281-n%5E%281%2Fn%29%29).

We should have

$$\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} (-1)^n \left[1 - (n)^{\frac 1n}\right] \approx -0.187859\ldots$$

The sum you are looking for is the opposite of the one known as [MRB constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRB_constant) and there is no known closed-form expression for it nor is it known whether it is algebraic, transcendental or even irrational.

Comment: Thank you very much.